# Is there an always callback for Ember.js .then function?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Assume I got an Ember `obj`. When doing any kind of sync with backend there is a possiblity to use a promise chain:

```
obj.save().then(function(res){
  // Success callback
}, function(res){
  // Fail callback
});
```

Is there a done/always callback for Ember.js promise chain with `.then()`?

I've tried adding a third parameter function, but it did not help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html#method_finally

Ember -> jQuery

1. .then()    -> .done()
2. .catch()   -> .fail()
3. .finally() -> .always()

Example (in the router):

```
var self = this;
var modelType = this.store.createRecord('modelType', {/* model attrs */});

modelType.save().then(function(model){
  self.transitionTo('model.show', model);
}).catch(function(){
  console.log('Failure to Save: ', reason);
}).finally({
  self.hideSpinner()
});
```

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer. Works great for me!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately there isn't. But you can create your own modifying the `RSVP.Promise` prototype:

```
Ember.RSVP.Promise.prototype.always = function(func) {
  return this.then(func, func);
}
```

So you can do the following:

```
// will show success
Ember.RSVP.resolve('success').always(function(msg) { 
  alert(msg) 
})

// will show error
Ember.RSVP.reject('error').always(function(msg) { 
  alert(msg) 
})
```

I hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Ember uses the RSVP.js library for promises, and RSVP [does not support `always`](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/issues/21?source=cc) due to not being part of the Promises/A(+) specs.

If you need it, @wycats suggests the [following approach](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/issues/21?source=cc):

```
Ember.RSVP.Promise.prototype.andThen = function(success, error, always) {
  return this.then(function(value) {
    var ret = success(value);
    always(value);
    return ret;
  }, function(reason) {
    var ret = error(reason);
    always(reason);
    return ret;
  });
};
```

Comment: Ember has a "finally" method: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.html#method_finally

Answer (score 0):

gorner's solution works but for Ember Data you have to add the following as well:

```
Ember.PromiseProxyMixin.reopen({
  andThen: function() {
    var promise = this.get('promise');
    return promise['andThen'].apply(promise, arguments);
  }
});
```

The reason is that the `DS.Model.save()` function returns a `PromiseObject` (see http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.PromiseObject.html), which doesn't implement `Ember.RSVP.Promise` but instead implements `Ember.PromiseProxyMixin`. So you have to make the `andThen` function available in that mixin in order for it to work with promises when saving models.